# Restrict IP's by code in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ddos

My server is under attack a DDoS attack so I want to restrict IP's.
I know how to detect DDoS in ASP.NET MVC (in ApplicationBeginRequest method), but is there also a way (in ASP.NET) to apply restriction on NIC, Windows Firewall or IIS?

Any ideas?

If I can restrict ip's on NIC level by code I will be a very happy person :)

Comment: If you don't have that many ip address to blacklist (this is a manual job), you can always use the ip restrictions module: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730889.aspx

Comment: I have many ip adress to blacklist, because of that I need to restrict them programmatically.

Comment: I recommend Dynamic IP Restrictions. http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/dynamic-ip-restrictions

Comment: I'n using it. But the attacks are a little bit clever. Flood is spreading 100s IPs so Dynamic IP Restriction rules are not enough. But still I can recognize each request is ddos or not.